# How to compare a list of elements from the web, locally?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

There are many tutorials but just can't figure it out... So i am practicing on https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html and trying to get the list of elements, and compare it to a list, to see that it is ok. Will do the same after sorting Z to A, and same with price. But i am quite a noob and beginner and really struggling. Until now i managed to get the list and reverse it (?)

```
const array1 = $$('.inventory_item_name').forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.getText())
        });
const array2 = $$('.inventory_item_name').reverse().forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.getText())
        });
```

If i try to compare these with === it will be true :/ i am trying it in VScode -Js - webdriverIO - Mocha

Comment: Can you include the HTML for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The provided link is hidden behind a login screen

Comment: Sorry, the login is written udner the login fields, if you just scroll down: standard_user pass: secret_sauce

Comment: You can't compare arrays using `===` sadly, because it checks refers, not a values ([The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)). You can find how to compare arrays [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript).

Comment: sadly this not help me. Or too advanced, and do not understand.

Comment: If you want add an answer, please post it as an answer instead of editing into the question

Answer (score 0):

Found a great tutorial on udemy

```
const itemNameLocators = $$('.inventory_item_name'); //gets the item names
const originalItemNameText = itemNameLocators.map(item => item.getText()); //maps the item names and covnerts to text (?)
console.log(originalItemNameText) //prints the value- item names- in an array
const itemNameCopy = originalItemNameText.slice() //creates a copy of the item names - not to change the original array
const sortedItemNames = itemNameCopy.reverse() //sorts the copied list - to match the websites copy
console.log(sortedItemNames) //logs it - for personal use only
expectChai(originalItemNameText).to.eql(sortedItemNames) //compares the 2 array texts
```

where I added the `.reverse()`, in this case the test will fail. without the `.Slice` it was passing whatever the values were and in what order. there it will be `.sort()`, and in the test case where I will sort on the page itself, I will change it accordingly. The same thing can be done on the price.

Of course, there was an easier way, just to check the first item name = x and when sorting check the name again to contain the last item, but that was too basic.